# Thread Synchronization Primitives

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I am looking for a good material on different thread synchronization primitives that are generic (not tied to any language or implementation. I only want the concepts).

Searches in the internet point to specific language or implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it will be hard to find such resources, because they are almost always accompanied with some (at least pseudo) code example. Unless someone better informed than me sees this question :)

I would suggest exploring wikipedia for starters, e.g.:

- [Producer consumer problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem)
- [Dining philosophers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem)
- [Sleeping barber problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem)
- [Synchronization (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronization_%28computer_science%29)
- [Inter-process communication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

look at the linked general words, links and external links, once you get familiar enough in the desired direction it would be ideal to find a scientific article that covers the topic - they are full of many references, and evenutally you'll stumble upon some great article(s).

Comment: Could also add the [Monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) article which covers the major synchronization primitives.